# Can I define a method of interface type inside a class

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
abstract class someClass
{
    public abstract IProduct SomeMethod();
}

public interface IProduct
{
    string Operation();
}
```

I have seen the above code having a method define inside abstract class with type interface, I wonder the use of this. Can anybody explain?

Comment: There are a gazillion usages of either abstract classes, interface etc. And for the combinations even more. Hard to tell the "killer" usage here.  An example from the Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.beginread?view=net-6.0 Stream.BeginRead

Comment: Are you just asking what interfaces are?  What abstract classes/methods are?  What the return type of a method means?  It's not really clear to me what the specific problem is.  Perhaps you have a more complete example which does something you don't expect or produces an error?

Comment: just want to know this line (public abstract IProduct SomeMethod();) method of type interface..didnt get this

Comment: @Nitinbhatia What do you want to know about it?

Comment: Just one example use: One class derived from someClass may return an instance of class A, another class derived from someClass may return an instance of class B (both A and B implementing IProduct).

Comment: This is usually used in factory patterns (google "Factory Patterns"), it doesn't matter what the actual implementation of the interface is as long as it adheres to the behavior and structure defined in the interface.

Comment: @riffnl yes I was going through Factory pattern where this line came

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about this:

```
abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    public abstract IProduct SomeMethod();
}
```

In this case, `IProduct` may represent any object that implements the interface, and the method `SomeMethod()` is guaranteed to return an object of some class implementing `IProduct`.

This has many uses where the design dictates that all classes that derive from `SomeBaseClass` be able to create objects that adhere to the `IProduct` interface.

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) interfaces are like contracts that guarantee specific behavior and properties.

This means that regardless of the actual implementation, code like this below is valid

```
SomeBaseClass f = ...
IProduct p = f.SomeMethod();
string op = p.Operation();
```